# Правильное Хранение спрайтов

Tags: unity3d

Есть класс GameResources, которых хранит стандартные характеристики мобов. Также есть метод, генерящий мобов. Он заполняет лист с актуальными мобами из GameResources через свой класс LevelData, генерит картинки под каждого, делает их детьми canvas (иначе не отобразятся).

В данном примере возникает ошибка в image.sprite = levelData.ActualMobs[i].Imagepath, так как спрайту нельзя присвоить string (логично), собственно, ее и хотелось бы избежать.

Суть вопроса: каким образом отредактировать код и исправить ошибку, чтобы изменение картинок все же было возможно? Вариант через создание огромного количества публичных полей и ручное занесение в них картинок само собой не рассматривается как кривой донельзя.

Из соображений использовать метод, возвращающий ассет по ссылке, но с такими не знаком.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Код:

```
public static class GameResources
{
public static readonly Mob skeleton = new Mob("Skeleton", 12, 12, 2, "Assets/Resources/Skeleton.jpg");
public static readonly Mob mushroom = new Mob("Mushroom", 8, 8, 3, "Assets/Resources/Mushroom.jpg");
}

public class NewBattle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject obj;
    public GameObject canvas;
 
     void Generator(LevelData levelData)
    {
        levelData.ActualMobs = new List<Mob>();
 
        for (int i = 0; i < levelData.RoomNumber; i++)
        {
            levelData.ActualMobs.Add(levelData.PossibleMobs[Random.Range(0, levelData.PossibleMobs.Count())]);
            print("adding");
        }
 
        for (int i = 0; i < levelData.ActualMobs.Count; i++)
        {
            int rnd = Random.Range(100, 400);
 
            GameObject child = Instantiate(obj, new Vector3(rnd, rnd, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            child.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
            Image image = child.GetComponent<Image>();
            image.sprite = levelData.ActualMobs[i].Imagepath;
            print("creating");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Тебе [это](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html) нужно? Метод [Load](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html)

Comment: Да, спасибо....

Answer (score 0):

Забавно, но проблема изменения источников оказалась связана не только с необходимостью использовать Resources.Load, но и тем, что для изменения Image.sprite надо менять вовсе не его, а Image.overrideSprite. Хоть из названия это и следует, но для понимания сути пришлось залезть в сам класс, и узнать, что такое поле вообще существует.

Следовательно, в данном случае необходимо заменить всего одну строку:

image.overrideSprite = Resources.Load(levelData.ActualMobs[i].Imagepath);

Вопрос закрыт.